# Angular 6 Post Request to .NET Core API

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, angular6

I am working with angular 6 trying to send a post request using httpclient , but always receive null body on the server side.

```
 save( rules:RuleModel[]){

let _headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' 
});

return this._httpClient.post(AppConfig.BaseUrl,JSON.stringify(rules), {headers:_headers} );   }
```

and API function

```
[HttpPost]
public List<Rule> AddTemplateTextRules( [FromBody]Rule[] Rules)
{
    try
    {
        return RuleManager.AddRule(Rules);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return null; 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To make a post request in Angular 6 with standard practice you need to do followings:

**In the service class:**

```
import {throwError,  Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Rule } from 'path';

@Injectable()
export class RuleService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
    private baseUrl = window.location.origin + '/api/Rule/';

    createTemplateTextRules(rules: Rules[]): Observable<boolean> {
       const body = JSON.stringify(rules);
       const headerOptions = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
       return this.httpClient.post<boolean>(this.baseUrl + 'AddTemplateTextRules', body, {
              headers: headerOptions
       }).pipe(catchError(this.handleError.bind(this));
    }

   handleError(errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) {
     if (errorResponse.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        console.error('Client Side Error :', errorResponse.error.message);
     } else {
       console.error('Server Side Error :', errorResponse);
     }

    // return an observable with a meaningful error message to the end user
    return throwError('There is a problem with the service.We are notified & 
     working on it.Please try again later.');
   }
}
```

**In the Component:**

```
export class RuleComponent implements OnInit { 
    constructor(private ruleService: RuleService) { }
    createTemplateTextRules(): void {

    this.ruleService.createTemplateTextRules(rules).subscribe((creationStatus) => {
      // Do necessary staff with creation status
     }, (error) => {
      // Handle the error here
     });
   }
}
```

**Then in the ASP.NET Core API Controller:**

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Rule/[action]")]
public class RuleController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost]
   public Task<IActionResult> AddTemplateTextRules( [FromBody]Rule[] Rules)
   {
       try
       {
           return RuleManager.AddRule(Rules);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
            return false;
       }
       return Json(true);
   }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Don't pass unbound methods as callbacks.

Comment: Tell me detail please.

Comment: `catchError(this.handleError)` is bad. If `handleError` references any other member of the class it will fail. Either use a free plain function, an arrow function, or `.bind` it to `this`. For more information read about how `this` works in JavaScript.

Comment: It turned  out to be a problem with the object I send to the server have some wrong values. But now I can receive the list on the server. Thanks a lot ,, I just was very new to angular 2 this is why I thought there's something I can't understand

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem has been solved! Please accept the answer as right answer by clicking on check icon so that it can help others with the similar problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest RxJS(Angular 14) here is the way:

**Service**

```
  Login(phone:string,password:string)
  {
    let _headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'accept': 'application/json'
    });
    return this.http.post(this.url,{username,password},{headers:_headers})
                .pipe(map(response=>response));
  }
```

**Component**

```
  async Login(phone:string,password:string)
  {
    let token$ =  this.authService.Login(phone,password);
    let token = await lastValueFrom(token$);
  }
```

Since I was returning just text and not Json from the API, this was my code to handle text response type in the **Service**. If you're getting a response parse error, explicitly defining the responseType will help since Json is default.

`Login(phone:string,password:string)
  {
    let _headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'accept': 'text/plain'
    });
    return this.http.post(this.url+'security/login?phone='+phone+'&password='+password,null,{headers:_headers,responseType:'text'})
                .pipe(map(response=>response));
  }`